# Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

so i have this code, in my LoginActivity, when i click on the register button, it shows this error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.vosk.demo, PID: 24098
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.vosk.demo/org.vosk.demo.RegisterActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320)
at ....
```

pleasee help me.
Edit:
My AndroidManifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.vosk.demo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ForgotPassword"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".VoskActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

a part of my login xml file :
[image]

[image]

my register xml :
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Start with the full stacktrace including the "caused by" exceptions and have a look at the element at row 13 of your layout.

Comment: thank you but how to do that?

Comment: Have you declared RegisterActivity in manifest.xml file ? Can you post xml code of RegisterActivity ?

Comment: You have the top of the stacktrace already in your question.

Comment: @laalto oh okay i checked th 13 line in my XML files, and didn't understand where the problem is :/

Comment: You are getting crash in RegisterActivity class. so please check and add XML code of activity_register.xml file in question, currently you added xml code of activity_login.xml.

Comment: you should share the code rather than images.

Comment: stackoverflow doesn't allow me to

Comment: I think problem is in your backgound image, Change `good_night_img` to any other image

Comment: okayy thank you so much